# Freya does not boot after kernel 3.19.0-51 update

Tags: release-freya, boot, updates

Samsung R580 Laptop  (Intel i5 Quad Core, 2.27 GHz)
elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit)
Single Boot Machine

Recently upgraded (using the Software Updater) to Kernel 3.19.0-51. After upgrade, the laptop will not boot normally. It falls down to a (initramfs) prompt. When I try to go into the recovery mode, I see the following error:

"/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root does not exist"

Has anybody seen this after an upgrade?

P.S. My old kenel 3.19.0-49 still boots fine, and I can boot into it by using the Grub menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for a solution I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551446/cant-find-lvm-root-dropped-back-to-initramfs) post on askubuntu.com.

```
$vgchange -ay
```

Allowed me to boot into the system. I did not do any more changes to make this a permanent change while booting up,since an update to my kernel came in today (to 3.19.0-56) and everything works off the bat again!

Elementary OS rocks!

Answer (score 0):

```
vgchange -ay
exit
```

also works for me, this is not a permanent solution though.